# About Get data after pressed a Row

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have project. I taking datas from Post Json . My model name is "model". I have a table. I did it with grid. I need take data ( `model[i].InvoiceID` ) after I press row and send value to another page. For example if I press first row I need get `model[0].InvoiceID`. If I press 2nd row I need get `model[1].InvoiceId` like that. But that row counts always changing. So I made rows with a for loop. So how can I add tap event like I asked? I tried with tapgesture in the loop but Its always giving error. Like index error or if I change it its always shows last index value. How can I fix it ? Thanks for advice <3
Its my codes :  ( counter is my model list count. )

```
for ( int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    var tga = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 };

    tga.Tapped += (s, e) =>
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(model[i].InvoiceID.ToString()));
    };
   
    var max = model[i].CustomerName.Length;
    if (max > 45)
    {           
            gr.Children.Add(new Label
            {
               
                Text = $"{model[i].CustomerName}".Substring(0, 45),
                TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
                FontSize = 16,
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,

            }, 1, 2 * i + 3);;           
       
    }
    else
    {
        gr.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = $"{model[i].CustomerName}",
            TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
            FontSize = 16,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,


        }, 1, 2 * i + 3);
    }        
    
    if (model[i].TransportTypeName == "ACİL")
    {
        gr.Children.Add(new BoxView
        {
            Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#a22227"),
            Margin=new Thickness(-6,-5)
        }, 3, 2 * i + 3);
        gr.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = $"{model[i].TransportTypeName}",
            TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.White,
            FontSize = 16,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }, 3, 2 * i + 3);
       
    }
    else
    {
        gr.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = $"{model[i].TransportTypeName}",
            TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
            FontSize = 16,
            Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }, 3, 2 * i + 3);
    }

    var ta = new Label
    {

        Text = $"{model[i].ItemCount}",
        TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
        FontSize = 16,
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };
    ta.GestureRecognizers.Add(tga);
    gr.Children.Add(ta, 5,2*i+3);

    //gr.Children.Add(new Label
    //    {
    //        Text = $"{model[i].ItemCount}",
    //        TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
    //        FontSize = 16,
    //        Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
    //        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    //        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    //    }, 5, 2 * i + 3);
   
    gr.Children.Add(new Label
    {
        Text = $"{model[i].ItemAmount}",
        TextColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
        FontSize = 16,
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    }, 7, 2 * i + 3);
}
```

This is what I want : https://prnt.sc/10og9fq

My Error when i click "ta" label ( That i tapgestured ) : counter is my model count. Its 6. So i have model[5].InvoiceId but still giving that error.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
```

If i make (count-1) its fixing index error but i cant use it. Becouse i must create labels with count loop. But even if i make it count-1 its just giving last index data.

Comment: please provide the **specific** error message you are getting and also explain if it is a compiler error or a run time exception

Comment: @Jason I edit my question for show error in a photo can you check it please ?

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: @Jason sorry. I edit again for show error.

Comment: that is a pretty basic C# error.  Your index is greater than the size of your array.  Use a `foreach` loop to avoid these sorts of problems, or fix your counter

Comment: @Jason yes its basic error but why its giving that ? Coz like i said its my counter code : `var counter = model.Count;` How it can be possible greater than my array ?

Comment: @Jason and even if i make it lesser Its just show last data. I need take datas for every row. Coz in every row data is changing.

Comment: what is the stack trace show?  Are you sure the error is not in the constructor of Page1?  check the value of `model[i]` to be sure it's valid.  Do some basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

the value of `i` is evaluated when the event handler fires, not when you create it

```
tga.Tapped += (s, e) =>
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(model[i].InvoiceID.ToString()));
};
```

instead

```
var tga = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1, 
          ClassId = model[i].InvoiceID.ToString() };
```

then

```
tga.Tapped += (s, e) =>
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;
    var id = label.ClassId;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(id));
};
```